# tkinter: callback not returning the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, callback

My function is not returning any value which i entered into entry-box on button click:

```
from tkinter import *    
import os


def onclick2():    
    val = box.get()
    return(val)    
root = Tk()    
box = Entry(root)    
box.pack()    
buttonfortxtbox = Button(root, text="Check Result", font=('Cooper Black', 9), bd=10, width=20,command=onclick2)    
buttonfortxtbox.pack(anchor = S)    
print(onclick2())    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can declare global **val** variable outside of **onclick2** function

Comment: The value is being returned, it's just not being returned to anywhere useful.

Comment: Where do you expect it to get returned _to_? When you click a button, nothing is listening for the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your code. But your understanding is not exact:

When you run this line: `print(onclick2())` you are trying to print the content of the entry widget which is empty when the program first starts. So that is perfectly normal you are not getting anything visible on the Terminal.

To see the content of the entry widget, modify slightly your callback as follows:

```
def onclick2():
    val = box.get()
    print(val)
    # You can remove "return val" as it is completely useless for your context
```

With this simple change, you will see `None` printed on the Terminal, which thing corresponds to what I described above. Now type something within the entry widget and click on the button: what you type appears finally on the output (Terminal).

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to print the content of your entry widget but you are using the variable for your entry to receive the content which is wrong. Also call print the content in your entry widget  to the your terminal .

```
 from tkinter import *


def onclick2():
    val = boss.get()
    print(val)



root = Tk()

boss = StringVar() # to receive the content in the entry 

box = Entry(root , textvariable=boss)
box.pack()

buttonfortxtbox = Button(root, text="Check Result", font=('Cooper Black', 
9), bd=10, width=20,command=onclick2)
buttonfortxtbox.pack(anchor = S)

    #print(onclick2()) # don't need to call this 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP is not trying to *"print"* anything, they've used `return` and have specifically stated in their text *"My function is not returning any value"*. The print function is not what they're asking about, it's the return function they've asked about.